# Get text after dynamic class with title text Python/bs4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The class "label" with text "Owner 1" dynamically changes so indexing the same class name isn't consistent. I'm trying to grab the name "Joe Smith" following the class text label. Some records have "Company Name" first.

```
    <div>
        <div class="label">Owner 1 Name</div>
        <div class="value">
        <div>Joe Smith</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="label">Company Name</div>
        <div class="value">
        <div>ACME CO</div>
    </div>
```

There are roughly ten "label" class in a row like the code above.
Owner 1 Name dynamically changes by record and ends up in a different location everytime. I just need the name value for each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
    target = soup.find("div", text="Owner 1 Name")
    print(target.find_next_sibling("div").get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
company = """your html above"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(company,'lxml')
target = soup.select('div[class="label"]:contains("Owner")+div>div')
print(target[0].text)
```

Output:

> Joe Smith